# Python: ReportLab: How to include page numbers in table of contents?

Tags: python, python-2.7, reportlab

I'm using the Python package ReportLab to create PDF reports.

Using the examples given in the user guide, reportlab website and forums, I've managed to achieve a dynamic table of contents with clickable links but the **page numbers aren't appearing** (in the table of contents).

It would be great if someone could point out what I'm missing from my code below:

```
from reportlab.platypus import Paragraph, Spacer, Image, PageBreak, KeepTogether
from reportlab.platypus.doctemplate import BaseDocTemplate, PageTemplate, NextPageTemplate
from reportlab.platypus.tableofcontents import TableOfContents
from reportlab.lib.styles import getSampleStyleSheet, ParagraphStyle
from reportlab.lib.units import cm, inch
from reportlab.rl_config import defaultPageSize
from reportlab.platypus.frames import Frame
from reportlab.pdfgen.textobject import PDFTextObject
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from datetime import datetime
import os
styles = getSampleStyleSheet()
PAGE_HEIGHT=defaultPageSize[1]
PAGE_WIDTH=defaultPageSize[0]

filename = 'report_template.pdf'
model_type = 'Cygnus'
identifier = 'X1'
date = datetime.now().strftime('%d-%b-%y')

class MyDocTemplate(BaseDocTemplate):

    def __init__(self, filename, **kw):
        self.allowSplitting = 0
        BaseDocTemplate.__init__(self, filename, **kw)
        self.pagesize = defaultPageSize

    def afterFlowable(self, flowable):
        "Registers TOC entries."
        if flowable.__class__.__name__ == 'Paragraph':

            text = flowable.getPlainText()
            style = flowable.style.name
            if style == 'Heading1':
                level = 0
            elif style == 'Heading2':
                level = 1
            else:
                return
            E = [level, text, self.page]
            #if we have a bookmark name, append that to our notify data
            bn = getattr(flowable,'_bookmarkName',None)
            if bn is not None: E.append(bn)
            self.notify('TOCEntry', tuple(E))


def report_gen(Test):

    def titlePage(canvas, doc):
        canvas.saveState()
        canvas.setFont('Times-Bold', 22)
        canvas.drawCentredString(PAGE_WIDTH/2, PAGE_HEIGHT/2 + 4*12, "Model Test Report")
        canvas.setFont('Times-Bold', 20)
        canvas.drawCentredString(PAGE_WIDTH/2, PAGE_HEIGHT/2 - 6*12, model_type)
        canvas.setFont('Times-Roman', 16)
        canvas.drawCentredString(PAGE_WIDTH/2, PAGE_HEIGHT/2 - 10*12, date)
        canvas.restoreState()

    def contentPage(canvas, doc):    
        canvas.saveState()   
        canvas.setFont('Times-Roman', 12)
        canvas.drawString(inch, 0.75*inch, "Page %d | %s %s   %s" %(doc.page, model_type, identifier, date))
        canvas.restoreState()


    def doHeading(text,sty):
        from hashlib import sha1
        #create bookmarkname
        bn=sha1(text+sty.name).hexdigest()
        #modify paragraph text to include an anchor point with name bn
        h=Paragraph(text+'<a name="%s"/>' % bn,sty)
        #store the bookmark name on the flowable so afterFlowable can see this
        h._bookmarkName=bn
        Story.append(h)

    #***Document Structures***#
    doc = MyDocTemplate(filename)
    frameT = Frame(doc.leftMargin, doc.bottomMargin, doc.width, doc.height, id='normal')
    doc.addPageTemplates([PageTemplate(id='TitlePage', frames=frameT, onPage=titlePage), PageTemplate(id='ContentPage', frames=frameT, onPage=contentPage)]) 
    Story = []
    toc = TableOfContents()
    PS = ParagraphStyle

    centered = PS(name = 'centered',
        fontSize = 20,
        leading = 16,
        alignment = 1,
        spaceAfter = 20)

    h1 = PS(
        name = 'Heading1',
        fontSize = 14,
        leading = 16)


    h2 = PS(name = 'Heading2',
        fontSize = 12,
        leading = 14)
    #*************************#

    #***Title Page***#
    logo = "logo.png"
    im1 = Image(logo, 112.5, 32.5)
    im1.hAlign = 'RIGHT'
    Story.append(im1)
    Story.append(NextPageTemplate('ContentPage'))
    Story.append(PageBreak())

    #***Table of Contents***#
    Story.append(Paragraph('<b>Table of Contents</b>', centered))
    toc.levelStyles = [
                        PS(fontName='Times-Bold', fontSize=14, name='TOCHeading1',
                        leftIndent=20, firstLineIndent=-20, spaceBefore=5, leading=16),
                        PS(fontSize=12, name='TOCHeading2',
                        leftIndent=40, firstLineIndent=-20, spaceBefore=0, leading=12),
                        PS(fontSize=10, name='TOCHeading3',
                        leftIndent=60, firstLineIndent=-20, spaceBefore=0, leading=12),
                        PS(fontSize=10, name='TOCHeading4',
                        leftIndent=100, firstLineIndent=-20, spaceBefore=0, leading=12),
                        ]
    Story.append(toc)
    Story.append(PageBreak())
    #***Content Pages***#
    doHeading('First heading', h1)
    Story.append(Paragraph('Text in first heading', PS('body')))
    Story.append(Spacer(1,12))
    doHeading('First sub heading', h2)
    Story.append(Paragraph('Text in first sub heading', PS('body')))
    Story.append(PageBreak())
    doHeading('Second sub heading', h2)
    Story.append(Paragraph('Text in second sub heading', PS('body')))
    Story.append(PageBreak())
    doHeading('Last heading', h1)
    Story.append(Paragraph('Text in last heading', PS('body')))

    doc.multiBuild(Story)

report_gen()
os.system(filename)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you solve this problem? Please this is my exact same problem now :(

Comment: did you solve it? please i would love to know you solution?

Comment: @JA-pythonista i would love to know how to make a table of contents with page numbers, using either report lab or wkhtmltopdf or any another python packaeg. thank you!

Comment: the solution is in the docs here: https://docs.reportlab.com/reportlab/userguide/ch9_other_useful_flowables/#tableofcontents